Drops row & copies to two different tabs within the same spreadsheet
current script:
function onEdit(e) {
const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const r = e.range;
if (src.getName() != "New Submissions" || r.columnStart != 18 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Escalation History"); 
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,18).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,18));
src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}

I receive google form submissions that I process daily. I have a "new submissions" tab of the results. I hit a checkbox and the row clears and moves to the "Escalation History" tab for documentation. I'm going to be sharing this spreadsheet broadly, so I want to be able to have the results be sent to 2 tabs - an admin tab for locked edit access, and a general tab for filtering & review (that way if someone messes up the data by accident, i have a backup tab).
Is there a better way to do this? I originally had the escalations history tab locked, but then it didn't allow the data to be sliced/filtered. I could be wrong - any other options here? Maybe I won't have to complicate it with trying to send the row to two different destinations.

If you want a "backup", why not just keep the "new submissions" tab?

an admin tab for locked edit access - not 100% sure what you mean by this, but if you protect that sheet, and allow no-one other than you (or a select few, for long-term management/security) to edit the sheet, then that sounds OK. In any event, as noted above, you've already got a backup - the original "new submissions" tab, as well as the Form itself which contains all the responses.
